# How to add <i> and <span> tag inside a tag in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My html code is given below:

```
<a  href="/patients/index" class="m-menu__link ">
    <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot">
        <span></span>
    </i>
    <span class="m-menu__link-text">
        Add Medicines
    </span>
</a>
```

and i want to convert it by using HtmlHelper in cakephp 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `'escape' => false` parameter in the `link()` method. This stops Cake from escaping the markup:-

```
<?= $this->Html->link(
    '<i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot"><span></span></i><span class="m-menu__link-text">' . h('Add Medicines') . '</span>', 
    '/patients/index', 
    [
        'escape' => false, 
        'class' => 'm-menu__link'
    ]
) ?>
```

It's important to remember to still escape any user generated content using `h()`. I've shown this in the example above by escaping 'Add Medicines', but if this is hardcoded you wouldn't need to wrap it in the `h()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The below code for add  and  tag inside a hyperlink in cakephp 3

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
       $this->Html->tag("i", "<span></span>",array("class" => "m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot")).$this->Html->tag("span", "Add Medicine", 
        array("class" => "m-menu__link-text")),
       ["controller"=>"Medicines", "action"=>"index"],
       ["class"=>"m-menu__link",
        "escape"=>false]
       );
   ?>
```